# output translations without document.write

Tags: javascript

I understand that `document.write` is evil and should not be used to output text on a website.

However, I did not find a better solution yet for my usage, where I output translated text via javascript on a page. Consider this:

My template code looks like this:

```
<h1><script>_e("title");</script></h1>
```

In a javascript file I have similar code like this to translate the strigs:

```
// Initialize the dictionaries and set current language.
window.lang = {};
window.lang.en = { "title": "Sample Page" };
window.lang.de = { "title": "Beispiel Seite" };

window.curLang = "en";

// Translation function that should output translated text.
function _e(text) {
    var dictionary = window.lang[window.curLang];
    var translation = dictionary[text];

    // BELOW LINE IS EVIL.
    // But what's the alternative without having to change the template code above?
    document.write( translation );
}
```

**Question**:

Can I change the javascript function to not use `document.write` to work without changing the template code? 
If not: What would be the best solution for translation here?

Comment: `document.write` isn't evil, there is nothing with it when used correctly (*ex: in this case*). Although if you insist [have a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first time using document.currentScript but i've tried this code and it should work correctly:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Initialize the dictionaries and set current language.
        window.lang = {};
        window.lang.en = { "title": "Sample Page" };
        window.lang.de = { "title": "Beispiel Seite" };

        window.curLang = "en";

        // Translation function that should output translated text.
        function _e(text) {
            var dictionary = window.lang[window.curLang];
            var translation = dictionary[text];

            var container = document.currentScript;
            container.parentNode.innerHTML = translation;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><script>_e("title");</script></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Another why is to use special tags or attribute to replace with something like jQuery, but this change your template. Something like

```
<span class='i18n-text'>title</span>

    var dictionary = window.lang[window.curLang];
    jQuery('.i18n-text').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        var translation = dictionary[text];
        $(this).html(translation);
    });
```

(i haven't tried the second solution but it should work :D)

Comment: That's two great options! Just a note: I found that `document.currentScript` is not supported by IE yet - but for me this is okay.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing the translations without using `document.write` - and with the added consequence (benefit?) of having text when you turn off Javascript or don't have a translation - would be to annotate elements that require translation and perform the translation after the document is loaded by changing the `innerHTML` or `textContent` (if you want to escape entities).

Your translate functions could be something like this:

```
function translateAll() {
    var dictionary = window.lang[window.curLang];
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-i18n-id]");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var el = elements[i];

        var translation = dictionary[el.dataset.i18nId]
        if (translation) {
            el.innerHTML = translation;
        }
    }
}
```

And you could execute it, for example, `onload`:

```
<body onload="translateAll();">
  <h1 data-i18n-id="title">My Title</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: A nice solution, though I'd need to change the existing markup of all templates... I'll consider it, since it allows me to change the language without reloading the page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js), the way to go would be to store your translation keys in computed variables, then write a translation service function that looks the translations up in a hash table. The thing that would make this trigger would then be an observable which you would do an attribute binding on the HTML tag with, setting the `lang` attribute. Changing this observable would trigger the depending computed variables to automatically re-evaluate and update your document. If using knockout is an option here, let me know and I will setup an example.